# How do I reference a class in MyScripts from within another namespace (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.3.5.  I have a script that I wrote under the Unity `Assets/MyScript` folder.

**ScriptA.cs**

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    //code here
    public static bool flag_I_want_to_reference;
}
```

Then, because I am using the Unity standard asset vehicle/car thing, it is in a separate namespace in a different folder path (i.e. not in `MyScripts` folder but in a different path under `Assets`)

**SomeCarScript.cs**

```
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car
{
    public class SomeCarScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //code here
        bool foo = ScriptA.flag_I_want_to_reference;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a `bool` that I want reference from within the `SomeCarScript.cs` but I am getting the error `The name 'ScriptA' does not exist in the current context`

I am trying to figure out what class/reference I need to have with `using` statements on the top of the SomeCarScript.cs script to make this work.  I have tried looking up global namespaces and tried `global::ScriptA.flag_I_want_to_reference` and `global::flag_I_want_to_reference` but that doesn't work.  I have also tried `using "Assets/MyScripts/ScriptA.cs;"` but that doesn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only obvious thing is the wrong spelling of `MonoBehaviour` which should be pointed out by the compiler, but that should give you a `Type or namespace not found` compiler error. If you wrote the code directly into your question (that's what it looks like), that looks like an honest mistake.

Comment: @EvilTak right, that's what it was, it's not the real issue here but thanks for pointing it out.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: Can you also tell us what directory `SomeCarScript` is in?

Comment: In the Unity editor, `SomeCarScript` is under `Assets/StandardAssets/Vehicles/Cars/Scripts`  `ScriptA` is under `Assets/MyScripts`

Comment: That settles it. Look at my answer to *this* question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38572363/4038191). Should solve your problem. Looks like the downvoter doesn't know what he's talking about :)

Comment: @EvilTak  Yes! This did.  Thank you so much!

Comment: It would be good to just copy and paste your code directly next time to prevent getting wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a compilation order issue.

If `SomeCarScript` is in a subdirectory of a "Standard Assets" folder and `ScriptA` is somewhere else, then it's because of the compilation order that `ScriptA` can't be referenced. `ScriptA` is compiled in a phase *after* `SomeCarScript` and therefore does not exist for `SomeCarScript`.

All code compiled in a specific phase can access code compiled in the *same* phase or an *earlier* phase, but **not** the code that will be compiled in a later phase (because, for the code being compiled, it doesn't exist yet).

General practice is to keep all code referencing the Standard Assets scripts in a folder *other* than "Standard Assets", so that it is compiled at a later stage and is able to access all other code.

Coming to your solution, you have *two* options:

1. Move `ScriptA` to the same directory as `SomeCarScript` (not recommended)
2. Move `SomeCarScript` to a directory which is not a subdirectory of "Standard Assets", "Pro Standard Assets" or "Plugins" (recommended)

Check out the [Unity Manual page concerning script compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html) order for more information.

Comment: This is perfect.  You are right.  I moved my `SomeCarScript` from the `Standard Assets` subdirectories into where my `ScriptA` is located and everything compiled and worked for me.

Comment: Don't know why I got the downvote. Would love a comment on whatthe answer does wrong, even though it solved the OP's problem.